# How to run new window.open and auto add Ctrl key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In ff & chrome Ctrl + click the url, it will open a new tab and the screen keep on the old url.
When I try to use javascript window.open it will open a new tab too, but the screen will change to the new tab.
How to use window.open open new tab and keep the screen in the old url ??

Or,.. can I use jquery auto add ctrl when I click url ??

**jquery**

```
$(".link").mousedown(function(e) {
   if (e.which === 1) {
      window.open($(this).attr('href'));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately comes down to how the browser elects to deal with your instructions. JavaScript does not have a notion of whether it is a tab or a new browser window that is being opened, for instance.

But something that might work, although probably differently across browsers, would be to blur the window reference that `window.open` yields:

```
var newWin = window.open($(this).attr('href'));
newWin.blur();
window.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `return false;` to David Hedlund's answer to get it to work under chrome and safari. I found with out the `return false;` my chrome opened two tabs.

Full jQuery

`$(document).ready(function(){
     $("a").click(function() {
    var newWin = window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    newWin.blur();
    window.focus();
    return false;
    });
});`

unfortunately there is a "flash" in chrome as the browser flicks quickly to the new tab and back.